# Storing CSV files to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datatables, schema

I'm trying to create an app that will store multiple csv files to a database.  I have a working app going, and it will store csv files of a particular format.  It looks through the header of the csv and stores each row of the csv with the column of the csv corresponding to the property of that row.  For example, maybe the columns are date, school, major

if the following row is like this:  05/16/16 |  Arizona State  | English

then we'll store an object with the date, school, and major corresponding to above.

However, I need to deal with csv files that have different names.  Some csv files might have the major column be named "Undergraduate major"  and others might have it named "Field of study."  Nevertheless, I want to be able to store all the csv files into my database even though the csv might have different names for the columns.  What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: if you use postgresql you can save all data in jsonb - it supports indexes and search inside it. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

Comment: would be great to see more examples of different data that you're trying to store.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to standardize the data rather than how to store it.  To standardize it, you can create a translation table that equates "Undergraduate major" to "Major", and "Field of study" to "Major", and even "Major" to "Major".  If you encounter a column name in a CSV file without a translation you can either just use it or throw an alert to tell you that you need to define a new translation.

Comment: ^@rd_nielsen, that's pretty much exactly what I need.  Do you have any documentation on how to do that with rails?